# About the equation $m^4+n^4=10m^2n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Solve the diophantic equation: $$m^4 + n^4 = 10m^2n^2 + 1.$$

[Hint: Use the discriminant of the polynomial]

I did $m^4 - 10m^2n^2 + n^4 = 1$
I know that if $\gcd(x,y)\mid c $ this can be solved, but I don't know if I can do this step.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you know pells equation?

Comment: It's $x^2−dy^2 = 1$ isn't it?

Comment: `Use the discriminant of the polynomial` Why not try to use that hint?

Comment: You should know that there are infinitely many solutions to $u^2 - 10 uv + v^2 = 1,$ this may be familiar as "Vieta Jumping."  There will be only finitely many solutions to your actual problem, correct treatment would involve factoring in $\mathbb Z [ \sqrt 6 ]$ I guess.

Comment: can you unaccept so I can delete?

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about "Vieta Jumping." is relationed with abstract algebra?

Comment: May, where did you get the problem? What is your background as relates to this problem?

Comment: It's a problem that my number theory teacher gives me but I only know diophantic equations (general) and something of continued fractions.

Comment: Alright, good that this comes with some individual attention from someone who knows you. I suggest you borrow Diophantine equations by Mordell; there are some results about homogeneous quartic forms set equal to constants. By the way, the solutions of the (much) easier $u^2 - 10 uv + v^2 = 1$ are consecutive entries of the sequence $$0, \; 1, \; 10, \; 99, \; 980, \; 9701, \; 96030, \; 950599, \ldots$$ with $u_{n+2} = 10 u_{n+1} - u_n$

Comment: Oh it's ok, I will see. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @May See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298639/find-short-and-simple-methods-to-solve-24x41-y2), since your reduced discriminant is $24n^4+1\,$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270728/solve-this-diophantine-equation-m4n4-10m2n21

Comment: @dxiv $3*7^2*17*n^4+1$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Not sure what that is, but it's certainly not the discriminant referred to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll try. The equation can be rewritten as $(m^2-n^2)^2-2(2mn)^2=1$. So, letting $x=m^2-n^2$ and $y=2mn$, we get the equation $x^2-2y^2=1.$ Hence, to get the solutions of the original equation, it suffices to solve the diophantine equation $x^2-2y^2=1$. But this new equation is precisely the question of finding the units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ with norm $1$. Note that the fundamental unit of this ring is $1+\sqrt{2}$ which correspond to $x=1$ and $y=1$. This fundamental unit has norm $-1$. In fact, the units in the ring  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ are of the form $\pm(1+\sqrt{2})^k$, where $k$ is an integer. So the units of norm $1$ are those units $\pm(1+\sqrt{2})^k$ where $k$ is even.

Comment: But is not true that an solution for $x^2-2y^2=1$ is also solution for the original problem, i.e. $x=3$, $y=2$ implies $m^2-n^2=3$ and $2mn=2$ which do not have solutions in integers.

Comment: @RicardoLargaespada you are right my friend. I should not said that it suffices to show. Sorry